# LINQ : saving files to a database

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

I want to save a pdf and mp3 file(s) to a SQL Server database and be able to retrieve from it.
I'm still starting out with LINQ and don't master it yet.

Comment: So do you have a more specific question or are you wanting us to write out all the code for you? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start off with your going to have a binary field in your database to save the file to.

Are you using LinqToSql, EntityToSql, or? Need some more information...

But once you get an object with a []byte to save the file to then it just a matter of making the appropriate Save() call... but with having some more information it hard to say.

Did you google tutorials?

Here is one that I found: [Uploading Binary files or Images using LINQ to SQL](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/03/using-irepository-pattern-with-linq-to.html)

Has example code and sql to generate dummy tables...

Comment: The link is broken, now links to something about IRepository usage.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert these into byte arrays (System.Data.Linq.Binary).  One line to load

```
var myMp3 = new Binary(File.ReadAllBytes(mp3Filename));
```

If you create your database schema (VarBinary in the database) and drag the table over from Server Explorer into the DBML designer, it'll do everything for you.